# Mongodb, count and sum

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{
_id:123 
"name":"Amy"
"Num_of_Friends":["Kim","Liu","Kelly"]}
```

Now I have this structure in MongoDB as above, how can I have an output that gives me the user's name that has the highest number of friends?